# Нужен поиск по тексту в изображениях в Google Docs. (OCR)

Tags: поиск, текст, распознавание-символов, google-docs

Подскажите, а есть ли решения для поиска файла по тексту в изображении? 
Мне нужно, что-бы когда я вбивал в поиск "Гедближе" или "Курица", то мне выдавало необходимый файл, или похожие файлы по метке курица. [image: 65412184121рпрп]

Сам файл может называться "65412184121рпрп" по этому мне от этого пользы никакой. Я не найду рецепта в Google Docs. По этому может есть какие-нибудь идеи, как это реализовать?

Я так понимаю в Google Docs уже есть свой встроенный OCR. Можно ли его как-то использовать для моих нужд?

Слышал есть сейчас самообучаемые нейросети, которые можно применять под свои практические задачи. Например платформа Google Colaboratory. Может их можно как-то совместить.

Спасибо за внимание, буду рад любой информации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно можно [Detect text in images](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr), но сначала вы должны зарегистрироваться в Google, как разработчик (платная услуга), а затем оплачивать пользование OCR сервисом

Comment: Благодарю за ответ